# Reading App.Config files and changing files, getting null reference exception

Tags: xml, app-config

I have the following code where I am trying to change the value in an app.config file depending on what value is entered into a field.  I'm receiving a 'NullReferenceException was unhandled' error and can't figure out exactly why.  Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks
erik
The relevant code

```
    XmlDocument xmlConfig = new XmlDocument();
    xmlConfig.Load(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
    string strRegister = txtRegister.Text;
    foreach (XmlElement element in xmlConfig.DocumentElement)
    {
        if (element.Name.Equals("appSettings"))
        {
            foreach (XmlNode node in xmlConfig.ChildNodes)
            {
                if (node.Attributes["key"].Value.Equals("btnTestClick"))
                {
                    if (strRegister.Equals("1"))
                    {
                        node.Attributes["value"].Value = "true";
                    }
                    else if (strRegister.Equals("2"))
                    {
                        node.Attributes["value"].Value = "false";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    xmlConfig.Save(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.SetupInformation.ConfigurationFile);
    ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("appSettings");
```

and the app.config contents

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="btnTestClick" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to write `element.ChildNodes` instead of `xmlConfig.ChildNodes` in the second foreach-loop.

Comment: ba-ha-ha-ha, oh I'm a doofus.  Yeah, you're right.  Thanks, I'd been staring at that for awhile and had a vaporlock in my brain.  Thanks again.